# How to change from "http:// " to "file://" using <a Href>

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, hyperlink

I have the problem in code behind using asp.net implement java-script in my code. I want use hyperlink when I click, it will open new tab for this file

I already use developer tool in my web browser for view page source to show my output.

```
data += "<td><a href='..\\" + reader["Link"].ToString() + "' target='_blank''>" + reader["FileName"].ToString() + "</a></td>";
```

output from developer tool will show like this

```
http://server001/d$/wwwroot/test_system/SaveAttacmentFolder/test%20PO%2011005488%ABC%2008-01-19.pdf
```

actually must show like this

```
file://server001/d$/wwwroot/test_system/SaveAttacmentFolder/test%20PO%2011005488%ABC%2008-01-19.pdf
```

Comment: `file://locationserver` won't be correct either

Comment: I use server for run this program.. just change name.

Comment: So you have a server and you have placed the file there. Is it right? Why do you want `file://` rather than `http://`?

Comment: @शेखर because if I use  http:// the output in my browser show  "Server Error -404 - File or directory not found." what I realize is the url automatic put "http://" at front my URL output, when I change manually this URL from http:// to file:// it the pdf file will show.

Comment: You file is in the same directory where your application is. Then there should not be issue like 404. You should provide more detail what do want to achieve.

Comment: @शेखर my file is different directory, that why I put "..\\" for delete path in this system, is  because data from " reader["Link"].ToString()" it will show path file.

Comment: Your application is on internet? I don't think what you are trying is a good idea because you are exposing a drive on internet which is not good at all. You should look for other approach. Like create a aspx file or some other http handler which you are using create a function to get data from there and then call this method or page etc

Comment: @शेखर my application is not on the internet, I just run on local intranet. That why I used this method because only certain account can access this application.

Comment: what is the value of `reader["Link"].ToString()`? If you don't put anything like http or https browser will automatically put it before your url.

Comment: @शेखर the value for reader["Link"].ToString() is /d$/wwwroot/test_system/SaveAttacmentFolder/test%20PO%2011005488%ABC%2008-01-19.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code like this

```
data += "<td><a href='file://" + reader["Link"].ToString() + "' target='_blank''>" + reader["FileName"].ToString() + "</a></td>";
```

If the `/` is causing any issue you can use escape cahracter

try

```
data += "<td><a href='file://server001" + reader["Link"].ToString() + "' target='_blank''>" + reader["FileName"].ToString() + "</a></td>";
```

You `reader["Link"].ToString()` value is

```
/d$/wwwroot/test_system/SaveAttacmentFolder/test%20PO%2011005488%ABC%2008-01-19.pdf
```

appending `file://server001` it should be

```
 file://server001/d$/wwwroot/test_system/SaveAttacmentFolder/test%20PO%2011005488%ABC%2008-01-
```

Comment: when I use this code the URL will show "http://server001/test_system2/file:/d$/wwwroot/test_system/SaveAttacmentFolder/test%20PO%2011005488%ABC%2008-01-19.pdf", when I put "../" data += "<td><a href='..//file://" + reader["Link"].ToString() + "' target='_blank''>" + reader["FileName"].ToString() + "</a></td>"; the url will show http://server001/file:/d$/wwwroot/test_system/SaveAttacmentFolder/test%20PO%2011005488%ABC%2008-01-19.pdf